# How to I associate a javascript function with the closing of the file chooser dialog?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm dynamically building a tabbed display of files based on user input from the file chooser that is 
displayed for input type=file

```
<input type="file" id="selectedFiles" style="display: none;" multiple/>
<input type="image" src="file_select_button_image.png" onClick="buildFileTabs();"/>
```

The problem is that when the user clicks on the file select button the file chooser is displayed AND`buildFileTabs` is called().  This is happening with the chromium browser.  I have not tried any other browsers.

How to I associate the `buildFileTabs()` function with the closing of the file chooser dialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `onchange` event on the `<input type="file" />`.

```js
function showFilePicker() {
    document.getElementById("selectedFiles").click();
}

function buildFileTabs(e) {
    var msg = "Selected "+ this.files.length+" files";
    var div = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
    div.innerHTML = msg;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="selectedFiles" style="display: none;" multiple onchange="buildFileTabs.call(this, event)" />
<input type="button" value="file_select_button_image.png" onclick="showFilePicker();"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but no joy.  Adding an onchange to the input tag resulted in nothing happening, i.e. no file chooser, when the file select button is clicked.

Comment: @user903724 - Works for me.  Run the code snippet I've added to my answer.

Comment: gilly, thanks for following up, it works for me too!  I must have looked at 25 pages about type=file and not one showed the explicit click() that you added.  Thanks again for sticking with me on this.